# Validación de usuarios en Web Server Rest

Tags: mysql, webservice, delphi-berlin

Buenas estimados colegas, apreciaría su ayuda en el tema, Explico un poco, 
Estoy haciendo una aplicación del tipo WebServer-Cliente en arquitectura REST (en Delphi 10.2) y MySQL (como manejador de base de datos). Del lado el servidor tengo una tabla de usuarios con login, contraseñas y otros datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, mi pregunta puede ser más de concepto que de otra cosa, debido que es mi primera aplicación de esa arquitectura.

Al hacer la conexión, yo uso un usuario con todos los privilegios en MySQL (en la imagen ramosjairo) para poder validar al usuario que intenta iniciar sección, como se ver en la imagen a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta de validación del usuario en la base de datos funciona bien. Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente, como hago ahora para que cuando un usuario quiera hacer un cambio en la base de datos la base yo sepa que usuario hizo el cambio. Ya que hice una tabla de cambios (Log) de las base de datos sujetas a modificaciones por medio de trigger, generan un registro en la tabla -log-, (ver fragmento del codigo de los trigger) y siempre aparece el mismo usuario aunque los cambios los hayan realizados usuarios distintos.

```
create trigger ModificarUsuario after update
on usuarios
for each row
  insert into log (id, fecha, usuario, Operacion, Tabla, Registro)
  values(null,now(),user(),'Modificacion','Usuarios', new.Id_Usuario);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer debo iniciar la sección para cada usuario pero no tengo idea de cómo realizarlo. Espero que me puedan ayudar, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En arquitectura de 3 capas (presentación/lógica de negocio/almacenamiento) la conexión de la lógica de negocio con la BD usa casi siempre un único usuario de BD<sup>1</sup>; el usuario que usas para autenticar en la capa de presentación no tiene nada que ver con el usuario de BD.

Así, para la BD `user()` siempre será el usuario de conexión a la BD, no tiene ni idea de qué usuario de presentación es el que ha iniciado el cambio.

La solución al problema es pasar esa información del usuario mediante las instrucciones DML; por ejemplo añades un campo "ultimaModificación" donde se guarda el usuario que hace la modificación, y al ejecutar el trigger también guardas esa información en un log.

En entornos más restrictivos no es infrecuente configurar los permisos de forma que los usuarios de BD no tengan acceso a las tablas y que queries y modificaciones de datos se hagan a través de procedimientos de base de datos, que incluyen lógica para controlar y registrar los accesos.

---

<sup>1</sup>Por aplicación. Puede pasar que accedas a una base de datos con un usuario con permisos de lectura y escritura desde la aplicación de contabilidad, y con un usuario distinto con solo permisos de lectura desde el datawarehouse.

Comment: Veamos SJuan76, Si mal no entiendo, mi solución estaría resuelta por pasar de alguna forma del lado del servido quien hizo el cambio y de alli al MySql. Se me ocurre incluir entonces un campo mas en las tablas indicando el usuario. 
Muchisimas gracias por la pronta respuesta hermano.